# FFMPEG Sync Audio & Video From Pi Camera & USB Microphone

Tags: video, ffmpeg, audio, sync

[Posted this in the Raspberry Pi community](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/25962/sync-audio-video-from-pi-camera-usb-microphone), but it got closed for being off topic. Reposting in the hopes that it is now in the right place.

I am trying to stream low-quality audio & video from my Raspberry Pi to another device. I have a Raspberry Pi camera & a USB microphone. Both devices work separately but i cannot seem to get the audio & video to sync up.

I am running Raspbian. I began by compiling ffmpeg as described at http://blog.giuseppeurso.net/raspberry-pi-streaming-webcam/.

Here is my ffmpeg info:

```
ffmpeg version 1.0.10 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Oct 27 2014 00:14:25 with gcc 4.6 (Debian 4.6.3-14+rpi1)
  configuration: --enable-filter=movie --enable-filter=aresample --enable-avfilter
```

Before i get streaming working, i want to just dump the audio & video to an MKV file. I wrote this script to dump audio & video to out.mkv until terminated.

```
#!/bin/bash

vpipe=/tmp/videopipe
apipe=/tmp/audiopipe
vw=320
vh=240
fps=15

trap "rm -r $vpipe" EXIT
trap "rm -r $apipe" EXIT

if [[ ! -p $vpipe ]]; then
    mkfifo $vpipe
fi

if [[ ! -p $apipe ]]; then
    mkfifo $apipe
fi

raspivid -t 0 -w $vw -h $vh -fps $fps -o - > $vpipe &
arecord -D plughw:1,0 -r 16000 > $apipe &

ffmpeg \
    -y \
    -fflags nobuffer \
    -r $fps \
    -i $vpipe \
    -fflags nobuffer \
    -analyzeduration 0 \
    -i $apipe \
    -map 0:0 \
    -map 1:0 \
    -filter:a aresample=async=1 \
    -c:a copy \
    -c:v copy \
    out.mkv
```

The audio & video are grossly out of sync. I have tried changing the framerates on both raspivid & ffmpeg with no success. Not sure what piece of the puzzle i am missing.

Comment: Have you tried starting ffmpeg in the background before arecord / raspivid?  So the pipe buffers don't fill up before ffmpeg starts reading from them.  Prob. doesn't account for "gross" sync error.  Maybe get ffmpeg to read directly from alsa and the camera, if it's a V4L2 /dev/video device?  IDK, just a couple ideas since I saw this question while looking for something else...